# MS Word, keep text together

Tags: microsoft-word

I just put this in an MS Word document:

> 2.1.4.1   Test case 6add a single user Initial state: App launched, at home screen
>   Action:
>   • Click “new”
>   • Click “invite”
>   • Select a single user from the ‘phone’s contact list when it appears
>   • Click ok in contact list to return to app
>   Expected result:
>   • User is added to list of invitees
>   • “Send invitations” is not enabled as neither time nor location yet have selected
>   CleanUp: press cancel before sending the invitation

The final line is  pushed over onto the next page.

Obviously, I would prefer to have all of it together. How do I do that?

I tried `paragraph / widow & orphan / keep lines together` over the whole thing.

How do I keep it all on the same page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select all of the text, go to the "Paragraph", "Line and Page Breaks" tab, and check the "Keep with next" box.  (Technically, you should not select the last line of the text.)  "Keep lines together" is for multiple lines within a paragraph where there is no carriage return / paragraph break.  "Keep with next" is for something like this with multiple lines / bullets / carriage returns and you want all of it to stay together.

[image]